# How to make a condition that if there is a data it will render that data but if there are none it will simply render null

Tags: reactjs, rendering

I am basically fetching data from an movie api (I use React). Some movies have 1 genre and some have 2 or more.

When a movie have 2 or more genres, I have no problems rendering them because I only want to render 2 genres (array 0 and 1), however when the movie have only 1 genre I get errors when rendering the 2nd genre because there are no data in it.

Is there a way to make a condition so that when there is no data from the 2nd genre it will not render anything and will only render the 1st genre?

Here is the code

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use either [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) or `&&` as:

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-sara-brfxq?file=/src/App.js:393-448)

```
  {data.genre[1].name} / {data.genre[1]?.name}
```

or

```
  {data.genre[1] && data.genre[1].name}
```

If you want `/` in between only if `data.genre[1].name` will show

```
{data.genre[1] && " / " + data.genre[1].name}
```